# Sort Multidimensional array of specific class swift

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, swift2

I have a class:

```
   class Rates{
var price:Double?
}
```

Multidimensional Array:

```
var rates:[[Rates]] = [[],[],[],[],[]]
```

I am trying to sort every array in rates from smallest Double to Largest. Here is what I tried

```
 for x in 0 ..< 4 {

      self.shippingRates[x].sort({ (Rates, Rates2) -> Bool in
                            return Rates.price < Rates2.price
                        })
                    }
```

But for some reason the sort isn't working, when i display the data it doesn't show up sorted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: none of them are being sorted, i did < rates.count as well

Comment: Edited the post, I had rates2.price in the code :/ still doesnt sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `sort` returns a new array, which you didn't retain. Use `sortInPlace` instead:

```
for x in 0 ..< 4 {
    self.shippingRates[x].sortInPlace { $0.price < $1.price }
}
```